# Laravel phpunit undefined assertResponseOk() method

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Whenever I try to use assertResponseOk()  I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Tests\Unit\LessonsTest::assertResponseOk() in
>   /home/faasdril/public_html/test/tests/Unit/LessonsTest.php on line 19

I can use other assertion methods  and I've extended TestCase class correctly

I'm using latest version of laravel

Comment: Maybe show your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method is no longer available in Laravel 5.4. From the [upgrade notes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/upgrade):

> Laravel 5.4's testing layer has been re-written to be simpler and lighter out of the box. If you would like to continue using the testing layer present in Laravel 5.3, you may install the laravel/browser-kit-testing package into your application.